# Deleting a symbolic link in java

Tags: java, symlink

Is there any api available to delete a symbolic link using java.
Files.delete(Path) didn't work out.Please post your suggestions.

Comment: Deleting a symbolic link should work the same way as a normal file. Can you share your code or the exception which should be thrown in case it doesn't work.

Comment: In which way it 'didn't work out' ? `Files.delete()` should delete a symbolic link OK.

Comment: is the symbolic link broken, i.e. its target does not exist?

Comment: Did not worked means? Did you get any exception ?

Comment: What do you mean by "didn't work out"? Can you show us code you are using? Did you get any errors/exceptions? Or maybe you wanted to delete linked file but you only deleted link?

Answer (score 5):

Files.delete(Path) is working perfectly on symbolic links. You should have a other issue in your code.

This code sample works (JAVA 8):

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
...
String symLinkName = "/some/path/to/symlink";
try {               
    if(Files.exists(Paths.get(symLinkName))) {              
        Files.delete(Paths.get(symLinkName));
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    log.info("Cannot delete symbolic link " + symLinkName);
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Remember that symbolic links are a UNIX concept and does not exist on Windows

Answer (score 0):

I'll just go ahead and say that I think that

> Remember that symbolic links are a UNIX concept and does not exist on Windows

is not correct, at least not completely. Windows do have concept of symbolic and hard [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/mklink) which probably does differentiate in some parts from Unix concept. I could be completely wrong.

But this is not the main point of my reply, I actually ran into same kind of problem, I was not able to remove "symbolic link" which, in fact, was not even symbolic link. I created this symbolic link on Unix and transferred those directories to Windows machine and tried to remove that "symbolic link" with Java NIO, but it failed with `java.nio.file.DirectoryNotEmptyException`. If I create symbolic link on Windows as instructed in the link above, everything works fine from Java.

I know this is pretty specific scenario, but here's my 2 cents.

Answer (score -3):

Some more information to symbolic links are found [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/links.html). If you cant remove the link you can do it with a `ProcessBuilder`-class in Java and try it with your bash/cmd-command (depends on your used system).

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("<bash you use>", "rm", "<filepath>");
Process p = pb.start();
```

But normaly you can delete symbolic links with:

```
Files.delete("path");
```

The directory needs to be empty. if the Path is a symbolic link, then the link is deleted and not the target that it represents.