# How to delete all files in directory but keep the file that a symbolic link is pointing to?

Tags: java

This has been identified as a possible duplicate of another question on here, it is not. I know how to delete the symbolic link and the files. I am trying to keep the file associated with the symbolic link but delete everything else.

My Problem: Delete all files in directory older than 7 days except files associated with symbolic link.

Issue: Symbolic link successfully deleted but remaining older files are not removed.

Details: I am trying to write a simple Java program to delete all of the files and subfolders in a directory older than 7 days which is working but there is one issue. If there is a symbolic link then I need to delete just the link and keep the file that it links to. Other than that case, everything else gets deleted. I know that I am very close... if you have any suggestions let me know please. At the moment I am able to have it delete the symbolic link but the other old files are not being deleted when they should. This could be a simple logic error or maybe I am approaching the problem the wrong way. Thanks in advance!

```java
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class delcache {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        String path1="/home/test/cachetest";
        recursiveDelete(7, path1);
    }

    public static void recursiveDelete(int days, String dirPath) throws IOException {

        long cutOff = System.currentTimeMillis() - (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
        Files.list(Paths.get(dirPath))
        .forEach(path -> {
            if (Files.isDirectory(path)) {
                try {
                    recursiveDelete(days, path.toString());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // log
                }
            } else {
                try {

                    if (Files.getLastModifiedTime(path).to(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS) < cutOff) {

                        String pathsave = null;

                        if(Files.isSymbolicLink(path)) {
                            pathsave = path.toRealPath().toString();
                            System.out.println("pathsave: " + pathsave);
                            System.out.println("delete symlink: " + path);
                            Files.delete(path);
                        }


                        if(!(Files.isSymbolicLink(path))) {

                            System.out.println("pathsave: " + pathsave);
                            if(!(path.toString().equals(pathsave))) {
                                System.out.println("not equal so delete file: " + path);
                                Files.delete(path);
                            }



                        }

                        //Files.delete(path);

                    }
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    // log
                }
            }
        });
    }


}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deleting a symbolic link in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32227183/deleting-a-symbolic-link-in-java)

Comment: Just so I understand, the symbolic links and the filenames are in the same folder? And you want to delete a *link* if the corresponding *file* is older than 7 days? If more than one symlink point at the same file, should all of them be deleted? If you delete the symlink, does that mean that you intend for the corresponding file to be deleted on the next pass through the directory (since it already was more than 7 days old, and now it no longer has a symlink pointing to it)?

Answer (score 0):

You could use this method:

1. Use `Process process = Runtime.getRuntime.exec("ls -l")` to list all contents of the directory.
2. Read the `InputStream` of `process` line by line.
3. If the first character is 'd', the file in the line is a directory. Recurse.
4. If the first character is '-', delete.
5. If the first character is 'l', it is a symbolic link. Skip the file.

You can get the filename from the same line. For example, if the line is in a variable 'str', the the filename is `str.split("\\s+")[8]`

You can additionally use the filenames for any other checks you require.

---

EDIT

Untested method using `grep`:

```
String getLinkedFile(file) {
// Input: A Symbolic link file
// Output: Name of file pointed to by the symlink

    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime.exec("ls -l | grep -e \"->\"");
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        String []tokens = line.split("\\s+");
        String linkFile = tokens[8];
        if(linkFile.equals(file.getName()))
            return tokens[10];
    }
    return null;
}
```

You may need to modify this function based on file paths.

Comment: Is there a way to do it like I am doing it now? I posted my code above as an example of how I am doing it. I was hoping that there would be a small change I could make to my current code that would fix this issue. Also, I am needing to delete the symbolic links, just not the file that they are linking to. I can successfully delete all of the files but when trying to perform this condition it is not working.

Comment: Check the edit. The function provided may be of use.

Comment: Parsing `ls` is a path toward failure. Much better to use `Files.isSymbolicLink`.

Comment: But how do you get the file the symlink links to?

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is flawed, `String pathsave` persists only for the current loop of the specific path. when the loop gets to actual file the `pathsave` is always null.
if you want to save the symbolic links path you need to have a list of paths which is outside the function. even then it won't work because you have no guarantee for any order, you may first reach to the symbolic link or first reach the file.

So as I understand it you must first iterate the folder looking for all the symbolic links, save them into global `List` which is accessible to the method, and then run and delete the files.
**side note**: notice that if you delete the symboic links, the next time you would run this function, the same files which previously had symlinks will now be deleted

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
    String path1="/home/test/cachetest";
    List<Path> symlinks = getAllSymLinks(path1);
    recursiveDelete(7, path1, symlinks);
}

public static List<Path> getAllSymLinks(String dirPath) throws IOException {
        List<Path> paths = new ArrayList<>();
        Files.list(Paths.get(dirPath))
        .forEach(path -> {
            if (Files.isDirectory(path)) {
                try {
                    paths.addAll(recursiveDelete(days, path.toString()));
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // log
                }
            } else {
                try {
                    if(Files.isSymbolicLink(path)) {
                        paths.add(path.toRealPath());
                    }
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    // log
                }
            }
        });

        return paths;
}

public static void recursiveDelete(int days, String dirPath, List<path> symlinks) throws IOException {
    long cutOff = System.currentTimeMillis() - (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
    Files.list(Paths.get(dirPath))
    .forEach(path -> {
        if (Files.isDirectory(path)) {
          try {
              recursiveDelete(days, path.toString(), symlinks);
          } catch (IOException e) {
            // log
          }
        } 
        else {
          try {
            if (Files.getLastModifiedTime(path).to(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS) < cutOff &&
                !Files.isSymbolicLink(path) &&
                !symlinks.contains(path)) 
            {
                 Files.delete(path);    
            }
          } catch (IOException ex) {
            // log
          }
        }
    });
```